# Why am I not getting mousePressEvents in a QGLWidget?

Tags: events, qt4

I am trying to catch mouse press events in a QGLWidget.  I am attempting to use the movements of the mouse to move an artificial cursor (a "floating" dot) in a stereo window.    I have reimplemented mousePressEvent in my own QGLWidget, here are the relevant sections of the .h and .cpp files:

the .h file

`protected:`

```
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent  *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent  *event);
```

Here is the function in the .cpp file

`void ImageGLView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)

{`

```
    if(FLOATING_DOT == mouseMode){  
        QPoint currentPos = event->pos();  
        lastPos = currentPos;
    }
```

}

Nothing fancy here...but my mousePressEvent never gets any events.  I set breakpoints, and take other actions, but those events are going somewhere else

I do get the mouseMoveEvents, so long as I have mouse tracking turned on.  If I don't have it turned on, I don't get them, even if I press mouse buttons while moving the mouse.  This appears to be contrary to the documentation and to all the QT references.  This makes me think somebody else is getting the mousePressEvents--but those text strings don't appear anywhere else in my code.

Given the simplicity of what I'm doing, I don't really know what to try next--I have done this precise kind of thing in other QT GL code without a problem--perhaps it is related to the stereo nature of the window?  Any other ideas?

details:  QT4.6, Windows XP

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in `bool QWidget::event(QEvent *event)` on the `mousePressEvent((QMouseEvent*)event);` line?  What happens when you step into that function?

Comment: not sure what you mean.  I put breakpoints everywhere in my function, none ever get reached--

Answer (score 0):

If you use Qt 4.6.2, then this may be a problem, because it's a very buggy version: QScrollArea lags sometimes, even QTimer don't deliver events while mouse pointer is not over the app window. You can try to download a more recent version.